# SwaggerUI - cURL - Incorrect Port

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger

I am migrating an old .NET core app.

Swagger is configured, but is not working. I.e. "failed to fetch".

I've narrowed this issue down to a CORS error.

Swagger was originally configured to call:
https://myapi.domain.com
on ServerOld

The migrated API is configured as:
https://myapi.domain.com:4343
on ServerNew

However, the migrated API's SwaggerUI is incorrectly configured.

The Swagger UI is rendering on:
https://myapi.domain.com:4343
But the generated cURL is pointing to:
https://myapi.domain.com

The Swagger configuration in my Startup.cs looks like:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUi3(s=> {
            s.ServerUrl = "https://myapi.domain.com:4343";
        });
```

Despite having port specified in ServerUrl property, Swagger cURL is still wrong (no port):

> curl -X GET "https://myapi.domain.ca/api/Authentication" -H "accept: text/plain"

What can I change to configure this?